# const problem in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, gcc

I have the shortest question possible:

Why does this not work in VS2010?

```
string keyword("lookuptable");
const int kwSize = keyword.size();
char oldBuffer[kwSize+1];
```

It works perfectly in GCC. VS2010 tells me that

> "expression must have constant value"

I am using Win32 console application / empty project.

I am using absolutely nothing special, just

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
using namespace std
```

and its a single main function in a cpp file.

Comment: I am using a simple Win32 console application empty project. I don't know if its 0x or not.

Comment: what is the type of `keyword`?

Comment: I updated the question, string.

Comment: Which version of gcc? It (correctly) fails to compile for me in gcc. Note: I always use `-std=c++98` or `-std=c++0c`.

Comment: What do you mean by "how do you solve it?"  You solve it by not doing that... use a container that can be dynamically sized, like `std::vector` or `std::string`, depending on what you need to do with it.

Comment: >> use a container that can be dynamically sized, like std::vector or std::string, depending on what you need to do with it. >> OK, I see it now, I'm just a beginner...

Comment: @Charles Bailey: 4.5.1. If I don't use any parameters, just the cpp file it compiles without warnings.

Comment: @zsero: Are your declarations at global scope as they appear to be? This shouldn't compile even with gcc extensions.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: I am using absolutely nothing special, just #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
Also they are not global, it is just a single main function.

Comment: @zsero: You could state all that in the original question; now that you have clarified I can see that it would compile with gcc's "VLAs for C++" extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of an array must be an integral constant expression, or ICE (which means that it must be known at compile-time).  You can use a `const int` in an ICE, but only if its initializer is itself an ICE.

A function call, like `keyword.size()` is not usable in an ICE, so `kwSize` is not usable in an ICE.

If it "works perfectly" in gcc it is either due to a bug or a language extension of some sort.

In C++0x, some function calls can be used in integral constant expressions, but they must be `constexpr` functions and there are restrictions on their use.  To the best of my knowledge, no compiler fully supports `constexpr` yet.  In any case, `std::string::size` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: In gcc it doesn't even give a warning. Can you show me how to fix it?

Comment: Yes:  compile with `-pedantic -std=c++0x` to make gcc reject invalid code.

Comment: make that `-pedantic-errors -std=c++0x` and I'll agree with you. `-pedantic` only throws warnings, even for things clearly forbidden in the Standard.

Answer (score 2):

GCC has a language extension allowing variable-length arrays. Visual C++ does not. You must initialize stack-based arrays with a fixed, compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, non-constant array bounds are a GCC extension (likely a side benefit of its C99 support - C99 does allow non-constant array bounds). If you want this in C++, you should use a `vector`:

```
std::vector oldBuffer(kwSize + 1);
```

To turn this into a `char *`, do:

```
&oldBuffer[0]
```

This, while not strictly speaking valid C++ prior to C++0x, works properly in every compiler I've come across so far. C++0x retroactively blesses this usage, and also provides a `oldBuffer.data()` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`keyword.size()` is evaluated at runtime therefore it is not a compile time constant. Depending on the compiler it may not be allowed to use an array size that is depending on some runtime value.

Some further info about [variable array length in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is there "expression must have constant value". The const has to be something resolved at the compile time.